# How should I handle multiple sagas with the same correlation id using J Oliver's CommonDomain library?

Tags: cqrs

I'm using Jonathan Oliver's CommonDomain library for my sagas. The SagaBase class has an Id property which is used as both the correlation id and a unique id for persistence. It doesn't look like it's possible to have multiple unrelated sagas share the same correlation id. How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should have multiple unrelated sagas that share the same correlation id. The correlation id is used to find a specific saga for a specific command/event. This is why the correlation id and saga id are the same.

Could you provide some more information on why you want to have multiple sagas that share the same correlation id, because I think you have to solve the problem using a different approach than finding a workaround for the correlation id.

Comment: Two sagas could have the same correlation id where, for example, they're both related to the same order and use the order id to correlate messages.